# "Symbol's value as variable is void: *" using load-file

Tags: init-file, syntax

I have this function in my config file and for some reason, I'm getting this error: Symbol's value as variable is void: *.

```
 (defun reload-config()
   "Reload config.org"
   (interactive)
   (load-file (concat EMACS_DIR CONFIG_FILE)))
```

I have a similar function that works right.

```
 (defun find-config ()
   "Edit config.org"
   (interactive)
   (find-file (concat EMACS_DIR CONFIG_FILE)))
```

Ps: I'm defining EMACS_DIR and CONFIG_FILE as

```
 (setq EMACS_DIR "~/.emacs.d/")
 (setq CONFIG_FILE "config.org")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From <kbd>C-h f load-file RET</kbd>:

```
Load the Lisp file named FILE.
```

I'm assuming `~/.emacs.d/config.org` is an org file, not a Lisp file. That is, it starts something like:

```
* all my amazing settings
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (setq whos-awesome 'i-am)
#+END_SRC
```

We can see that the first thing in that file is `*`; that is, just an asterisk. So when Emacs tries to *load* that file, it will look for the variable meaning of `*`, fail to find it, and throw an error.

If your file is set up as the example above shows, where all the Emacs Lisp is in `#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp` blocks, you can use `org-babel-load-file`. From its documentation:

> Load Emacs Lisp source code blocks in the Org FILE.

You can use it as follows:

```
(org-babel-load-file (concat EMACS_DIR CONFIG_FILE))
```

Comment: thank's a lot, you're a genius hahaha. The correct thing to do was to use init.el file, that has the babel load file stuff. Thanks for making me understand what was happening. I did know that was some silly error but I didn't know which.

Comment: Glad to help out! It's hard, because you see the asterisk in the error message, and it's not super obvious that `*` is the variable it's trying to look up.